# VBS, do while key pressed?

Tags: loops, vbscript, while-loop

I have a loop in vbs script, but I want to run it only when some key is pressed, e.g. "shift+9". For example each time i press those keys, my loop will send keys. when i stop pressing, loop is also stopped. How to make loop which runs when keys are pressed by me?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16207461/visual-basic-script-keypress-detection) might help

Comment: VBScript does not use an event-driven model. You can possibly use VBA, in Excel for example, for these kinds of situations. Chances are you have a problem X, picked an unsuitable solution Y and are trying to make Y work now. If you describe what the problem X is, the community might help you come up with a better solution.